# Generate valid openssh ssh key under windows

Tags: ssh, key, gitosis, openssh, smartgit

I've some persons that are under windows, and they need a public/private RSA keys pair in order to get them authenticated to gistosis, a GIT server. We use SmartGit as our GIT GUI, and this tool require the private key to be in the format of OpenSSH.

Using puttyGen, I've been able to get a openssh *public key*, that is printed in the window, but not a private key. I can only save a private key using the Save button, and it save a format that is not like the one we have using the *nix tool.

How can we use windows tool in order to generate a VALID openssh compatible public **and private** key ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can generate the keys anywhere, you don't need to be on windows to do so.

Comment: Yes you're right, however I'm the only linux user. I don't want the whole business to depend on me. I must document a universal solution that's good for Linux, Mac and Windows ( In our case that the 3 OS we're using)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

puttygen has a menu: Conversion -> Export OpenSSH Key That will save the private key to the openssh format.

Comment: i have saved the OpenSSH key but smart git keeps asking for it again and again .. !!